# Get buildings adresses around location with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I want to get address and coordinate of all building within some radius.
I can use http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=60.009719,30.354376&sensor=false&radius=2000
to get one nearest build adress.
Or I can get multiple results with 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=60.009719,30.354376&radius=200&sensor=false
The problem is that first request show me information about just one bulding,
second shows me a lot, but it show me organisation, not just buildings. 
Place api has place filter, but I can not determine right one for my case. Thanks.

Comment: what's an 'organisation' in this context ?